# Copy referenced files in VS2008/TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I'm using VS2008 w/ TFS. I have a commercial package that is a .NET dll and two other dll files that .NET dll uses. I want these files to be separate from the projects that use them.

I can easily make a reference in my C# project to the .NET dll and indicate "copy" so that it gets copied to the output (bin) directory to be used from there at run-time. But, this does not bring over the other two dll files the .NET dll file requires. I cannot make the same kind of reference to these other two dll files because they are not assemblies, COM objects, etc.

I can add a post-build command that would copy them, but while I can use $(TargetDir) for the destination, I don't know something to use for the source. I could use my machine's setup, but that will failure everywhere else.

I hope VS has some built-in mechanism for cases like this...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add the "other" files as content files to the project.

Add the files to the project

Select the file and **press F4** for the properties window

Set property **Build Action** to **Content**

Set property **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy always**

An other option is to do this with a build script.